# Obtaining light intensity from a greyscale image (python 2.7)

Tags: python, light

In my Physics Laboratory we are looking into light diffraction through a number of different slits. Then a camera captures the result. The image obtained has a number of white stripes separated by blackness.

How can I build a programme in Python that can measure the intensity of light changing over a single horizontal line on the image?

Comment: Judging by your question, you need an introductory Python tutorial

Comment: Stackoverflow is generally about coding issues of the sort "I have code X that doesn't seem to do Y", not for tutorials on the basics of programming. Look up tutorials on image processing in Python.